# push notification with custom icon

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, parse-platform, push-notification

I w'd like to know is there any way to send push notification with different icon than app's. I'm using Unity Parse SDK and able to send push notifications for both Android and iOS. Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You need to write a Unity3d plugin for your specific mobile platform.

Read the official unity3d manual for:

---

Android: [Building Plugins for Android](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html)

iOS: [Building Plugins for iOS](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html)

---

You need those plugins to call platform specific functions.

Comment: Again, thank you for answering but in theory I know it is possible. I'm searching for any clues for developing Android library project for this purpose. Can you refer to any tutorial that may help? Thanks!